# Running a Script in Foreground Without Login at Boot Windows10

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, background

I am trying to run a programme (t-rex, mining soft) which runs in the cmd indefinitely.
I want to run it **at boot without login**.
I have got it to run without any problems by scheduling a bat file, but it always runs in the background. I have tried the following...

file1.bat

`<complete path>\t-rex.exe arguments`

and

file2.bat

`start /wait <complete path>\t-rex.exe arguments`

I also tried to schedule at start,
`cmd.exe location=complete path, arguments= /k file2.bat or file1.bat`

Is there a way for me to either keep the process in the foreground or bring it to the foreground after login.

ps - My first post, apologies for any inconvenience if any. Thank you in advance.

Comment: By "foreground" do you mean you want the window to be visible on the screen?

Comment: Yea. I need to able to monitor what the process is doing.

Comment: Why not have it write to a log file. Then you can read the log file to see what it is doing?

Comment: Because it won't be real time. I will need to write an auto refresh script. Also there is potential for me to alter* the file contents if I leave it open with an auto refresh.

Comment: Why not just setup automatic login as that machine is probably only used for mining anyway?

Comment: Its for my personal daily PC. So don't want to remove the log in.

Comment: While it's possible to get things to appear on the Login Desktop/Login Windowstation, I do not recommend it.

Comment: I want to be able to look at the running process after I login. So i need one of two things. Either to keep the shell in which the task scheduler starter the process to be open or a way to fetch the process in a seperate shell.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet managed to find the answer. My workaround (like Ben suggested in the comments above) is to look at the log file. Colour coding is not preserved ofcourse so you just get live text.

It will display current log file in cmd. It will give you a live feed in powershell.

`type -wait <location of log file>`

This isn't ideal because...

1.No colour coding to catch important thing instantly.

2.The lag is noticible, hence defeats the purpose.

But anyway, I hope it's useful to some of you landing here on this page. GL